# Asus P4B SDRAM Upgrade

Tags: memory, sdram

I have to fix a PC for a friend - and - bought RAM because 256 MB SDRAM PC133 is not enough for WinXP.

I bought 2x 512 MB SDRAM PC133. If I insert one stick, it doesn't matter which one, the PC won't boot (there are some HDD Noises).

There are no Beeps (even if it boots with the old ram).

I think there's no speaker or something like that.

I updated the BIOS to the 2003 version (latest one) with same result.
I changed the RAM latency to the highest,same thing doesn't boot.

Does anyone have an idea what can I test/do now?